# SSIS package dataflow source is in green color whereas destination in yellow color

Tags: ssis

I am testin a dataflow task which is supposed to transfer some 3 lakhs of records from a source table of one database  to destination table of another databse.

i ve configured the fastload option.

then i executed my package ..as soon as the execution starts, the source becomes suddenly green showing something like  "300000 rows"

but the destination is in yellow color and after that there is no change in color even after some 5 hrs.when i checed in progress it is sayng something like "final commit is happening"

i tried the same activity by modifying access oprion without fastload option ..i can see the records are transferring to destination .but it is taking so much time.so what could be the solution?

Comment: What do you have set as the Maximum insert commit size: by default this should be 2147483647, it might be that it is inserting one row at a time rather than in a batch. Have you also looked in SQL profiler on the destination server for any locks?

Comment: I would remove the destination & drag a new one in its place & leave config at default - its easy to mess up the destination.